# what does "Christmas-like" mean?

Tags: meaning

> I thought this was absolutely brilliant on the Salvation Army’s part! People are more willing to support the men and women who protect us, no matter what line of work they are in. And who doesn’t like hearing bagpipes play on Christmas – there’s just something very **Christmas-like** about them. While not exactly an ad, this probably helped bring in more donations for the Salvation Army.

I know that  is  a Christmas-themed album fro,[enter link description here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christmas,_Like_a_Lullaby)

but here I can understand it in this sentence.

Comment: **[-like](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/like_73)**: suffix: "used with many nouns to make adjectives meaning similar to something". *an innocent childlike face.* *The illness causes chest pains and flu-like symptoms.*

Comment: so can we say who dosent like hearing bagpipes  can here Christmas-like?

Comment: No, they meant there's just something about "bagpipes playing on Christmas" that is very Christmas-like.

Answer (score 4):

There are certain things that are associated in people's minds with certain events or times of year.

For the English (as opposed to the Scots), bagpipes are not often heard at times other than around the turn of the year.  The New Year traditions that originated in Scotland are widely observed in the rest of Britain.

Therefore, the expression that hearing bagpipes on Christmas Day is *Christmas-like* indicates that it reminds the author of Christmas.  The author feels that *everyone* likes to hear the pipes at that time of year.

The suggestion that the playing of bagpipes would increase donations indicates that the author believes that everybody associates bagpipes with Christmas.  I can understand that this association would not be made in all parts of the world!

Comment: To be honest, as an English person, I don't associate bagpipes with Christmas *at all*. Buskers around town centres at Christmas time are invariably playing carols on either brass instruments or guitars, in my experience.

Comment: Indeed, I don't associate bagpipes with Christmas much either but I believe that is the gist of the quoted text.

Comment: I suspect the quote doesn't originate from England (though, having said that, the use of the adjective "brilliant" to mean "very good" is rather a British thing).

Comment: @DavidRicherby I read brilliant to mean "very intelligent."  That said, I've not heard bagpipes around Christmas in the US either, thank goodness.

Answer (score 0):

"Christmas-like" means exactly what it says: like Christmas.

Comment: thanks I understand it, but I don't know the sentence that applied this word.